# jax-ws invocation in Jersy

Tags: java, jax-ws

We have Rest services implemented using Jersy,my question is when invoking some soap service from our rest implementation, we are creating object for delegate like below,

```
@POST
@Path("/forgotuserid/validate/mobilenumber")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public ServiceResponse validateMobileNumber(CommunicationDTO commonDTO)
            throws ApplicationException, Exception {        
        ChMTYWebservicesProvidersWsMTY service = new ChMTYWebservicesProvidersWsMTY();      
        WsMTYPortType portType = service.getChMTYWebservicesProvidersWsMTYPort();
        //TODO : other stuffs go here   
        return response;
}

is there any way to avoid new object creation and have single here?
```

Comment: If `ChMTYWebservicesProvidersWsMTY` and `WsMTYPortType` are stubs of soap service (for example generated by axis), you can move them to util singleton class. It will be thread safe, because this stubs don't contain state.

Comment: i implemented simple signleton pattern to do that like https://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/singleton_pattern.htm, but people saying its not thread sage

Comment: public static CrunchifySingleton getInstance() {
  if (instance == null) {
   // Thread Safe. Might be costly operation in some case
   synchronized (CrunchifySingleton.class) {
    if (instance == null) {
     instance = new CrunchifySingleton();
    }
   }
  }
  return instance;
 }  is this ok ?

Comment: You can just have a static class with static field `WsMTYPortType` and initialize it in static block. So you will have only one instance of `WsMTYPortType` and it will be initialized at the startup and no check for `null` is needed.

Comment: I added as an answer what i mean. I think it will be more clear than in comment :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Spring framework then there is an option Dependency Injection , You can use that feature.

Comment: As we are not using Spring framework, can not have singleton object.

Comment: Create Singleton Class;

Comment: @sathishrtskumar public static Test test=new Test(); and use by ClassName.test

Answer (score 0):

You can code something like this:

```
public class SoapWSUtil{
   private static WsMTYPortType type;

   static {  
      type = (new ChMTYWebservicesProvidersWsMTY()).getChMTYWebservicesProvidersWsMTYPort();
   }

   public static WsMTYPortType getType(){
      return type;
   }
}
```

And then use it as `SoapWSUtil.getType()`. It will be thread safe in case, if you won't add state to `SoapWSUtil`